# SMTP client's hostname doesn't match PTR

Tags: email, smtp

I'm building an SMTP server and I'm struggling with an issue regarding hosts connecting to my SMTP server.

For instance, one client is connecting to my SMTP server with the given hostname: `EUR02-AM5-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com`.

Unfortunately, the server's IP doesn't match that hostname (52.101.131.25).

Based on the SMTP rules, I should refuse this email, but when I do a reverse IP lookup for 52.101.131.25, I get `mail-bgr052101131025.outbound.protection.outlook.com`, which **also comes from Outlook.com**!

So, even if the hostname doesn't match the IP, the IP is originating from a valid source in that case (outbound.protection.outlook.com).

And Outlook is not the only one doing so, here's the case with Zoho:

`HELO sender21-mail.zoho.eu` coming from the IP `185.20.209.254`.
But when you do a reverse lookup, you don't find `sender21-mail.zoho.eu`, but ... `sender.zoho.eu`

How can I do to ensure that both hostnames come from the same valid source, that's just the IP that is badly configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With content distribution networks & load balancing, the EHLO name and IP/reverse DNS often don't match. You could check the IP's validity against SPF records (not every domain has SPF records, but it is quite common). Taking zoho.eu as an example, the SPF record for the domain is

```
v=spf1 include:spf.zoho.eu -all
```

Which is essentially a ref out to the record spf.zoho.eu

```
v=spf1 ip4:185.20.209.0/24 ip4:31.186.226.0/24 ip4:87.252.213.0/24 ip4:84.207.209.0/24 ~all
```

185.20.209.254 falls within ip4:185.20.209.0/24 and is thus a reasonable source for messages from zoho.eu.

How to validate the source IP against SPF records depends on the SMTP server being used. There are [milters for Sendmail](http://www.snertsoft.com/doc/milter-spiff/) and [policy servers for Postfix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/SPF) that validate SPF.

Comment: Interesting. I do check the SPF, but haven't thought to do it via SPF early in the communication (I do it with the recipient). I'll check this out before accepting the answer but seems logical!

Comment: Yep, that's right. The SPF works where the IP/PTR verification lacks.